# JQuery not anticipating on return value

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm currently trying to use the return value of a PHP script to do a refresh action with jQuery. My PHP script is doing what it should do, return the value "reload" when a certain requirement is met; jQuery then however displays "reload" briefly and doesn't act on the refresh action that I've required it to do.

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '/bidstatus.php',
    data: { 
        sale_id: '<?php echo $sale['Product']['id']; ?>',
        token: '<?php echo md5(session_id().$session->read('Auth.User.id')); ?>' 
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    success: function(output) {
        if (output == "reload") {
            location.reload();
        }
    }
});
```

The PHP that returns the value, when a requirement has been met, looks like this:

```
echo json_encode("reload");
```

Also, to make it even more confusing, it sometimes does what it has to do, but it's not consistent at all.

So, am I missing something?

Comment: you are not returning a json value, change the `dataType` to `text`

Comment: He is using json_encode. Why would this not work?

Comment: What if you `console.log(output)` in the success?

Comment: Like expected sometimes I get an empty value, that's what the PHP script can return too; however, that still means that it should only refresh upon the return of the "reload" string.

Comment: My advice would be to make your PHP script always return something consistent like `true` or `false` or a specific string. Does the `console.log` log *reload* as a simple string? Show us the output. Also maybe have a look at the `cache` setting of the jQuery.ajax function http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: My cache setting is set to 'false', my console.log isn't showing anything for some weird reason.

I'll try the 'true' / 'false' setting.

Comment: My console outputs "(an empty string)", which is strange since I'm echoing "reload".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I saw this was still open and I managed to fix it myself, I'll post the code so it can/may help others with similar problems.

This was the code that fixed it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
setInterval(function() 
{

$.post('/bidstatus.php', 
    { 
        auction_id: '<?php echo $sale['Product']['id']; ?>',
        token: '<?php echo md5(session_id().$session->read('Auth.User.id')); ?>' 
    },

    function(data) 
    {
       if(data == "reload"){

        location.reload();
       }
       else{
        $('#shop-balance').html(data);
       } 

    }
    );

}, 1000); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, try this:

```
function do_ajax(callback)
{
 $.ajax({ 
    url: '/bidstatus.php',
    data: { 
        sale_id: '<?php echo $sale['Product']['id']; ?>',
        token: '<?php echo md5(session_id().$session->read('Auth.User.id')); ?>' 
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    success: function(data){
        callback(data);
    },
});
}
```

Just check it again and if you use any global scope variable then pass it through function's parameters.

And call it like this::

```
do_ajax(function(data) {
        if (data == "reload") {
            location.reload();
        }
    }
);
```

What I have done is to set a callback for your .success state, rather than direct code execution. Since Javascript executes the code asynchronously, it just passes the .success before the AJAX is finished, and thus, the data will not be "output" and it is "null" probably. You shoul add a callback there and execute it through a callback to allow the Javascript Interpreter to accomplish the task.

Comment: Well, do not use json, use default type, and then it will work.

Comment: Sorry, even changing it back to the default type didn't work.

Comment: And your request is get, set it to "POST" and retry it

Comment: Problem is not the dataType or the type of request. It can work with json, GET, POST, that only depends how PHP treats the request. OP didn't say that nothing was returned.

Comment: Indeed, my PHP returns the word "reload" like it should.